# Terrible trouble getting my head around OOP (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, xna

I've been using non-OOP languages (Mostly scripting or web development) such as Lua for a prety long time. I'm becoming quite advanced in C# now, but I've hit a rock as far as my current project is concerned.

I'm making a sort of game where you make a 2D environment out of various types of things.

I'm using an example I found on the web of porting XNA into a winform, and it works perfectly, no lag or anything.

But that's not my problem. I have absolutely NO IDEA how to make an instanced class communicate with another instanced class that the instanced class didn't instance.

Basically, I've made an "Insert" interface with a button to insert a peice of terrain, which then is meant to apear in Treeview1. How can I tell the form to "reply" that the user has picked the terrain (I'm using an enum for what they picked), and tell the form to add a node to the treeview?

Comment: You will get better answers if you show some code, as it's hard to tell exactly what you mean.

Comment: I'll edit now. Basically I want to communicate with other instances but the instance that's opening the communications didn't actualy instance said instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways object instances can communicate.  Often they will raise events and the other instance may have registered an event handler on that event.

Sometimes they will raise an event and a controller instance will have a registered handler and it will have references to various other instances and figure out what to do.

Comment: Wait, would I be able to static the instances? Or would this be simpler?

Comment: @Ashley Davies I would not static the instances.  Say the form instance which triggers the "dialog" instance registers a handler on the "ItemAdded" event.  When the "dialog" instance completes by the user clicking insert, the button can raise the ItemAdded event with the Item as a parameter.  Then form instance will then get the event and tell the treeview.  In this way, the form is acting as a controller.  There's lots of ways to skin this cat.

Comment: @Ashley Davies It might be more likely that there is a Model instance containing your entire datastructure.  Then the "dialog" instance can tell the model how to change and the model can change itself, raising "ModelChanged" events.  The treeview might be one of many objects registering event handlers on that event, all updating themselves appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple things that you could do.

You need to establish a mechanism by which you pass *references* between objects. Here is a little example of what I think your problem is, and a possible solution.

I'm going to demonstrate parent/child relationship.

```
public class Book
{
    public string BookText { get; set;}
}

public class Library
{
    private Book myBook = new Book();
}
```

In this case, the library can reference/talk/communicate with the book because it has an awareness of the book. But in this case, you have to create the book when you create the library. Let's change this so that we can add books to the Library.

```
public class NewBook
{
    public string BookText {get;set;}
    public Library ParentLibrary {get;set;}
}

public class BetterLibrary
{
    private List<NewBook> books = new List<NewBook>();

    public bool AddNewBookToLibrary(NewBook bookToAdd)
    {
        books.Add(bookToAdd);
        booktoAdd.ParentLibrary = this;
    }
}
```

Now, we have created a library that we can add books to, and the library can now talk to any book that has been added. It is within the library's ability to iterate through the book collection and perform some action on each book.

Also, each NewBook instance that has been added to a Library knows which Library instance is it's parent, and could access public functionality on the parent library.

This is a simple approach to hooking instances up. It can be applied to any class that you've created. The book and library classes could be replaced with controls and control parents or parent/child relationships in any object displayed in treeviews.

Is this answering your question?  Put a comment in and I'll update if you need more.

Comment: Sometimes I put the parent in the constructor: new Book(Library), so the book knows its parent at time of construction - depends on all the use cases.  Sometimes objects are allowed to be in multiple collections - at that point a different model is needed.

Comment: @Cade - I definitely agree on all your points. This was really only intended to be an introduction to the concept for someone new to OO. As mentioned, if more info was needed, I'd expand the answer to include more approaches if other answers didn't cover those approaches off already.

Answer (score 1):

Declare, raise an event and consume it.

The verb form of instance is "instantiate".

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it sounds like you need an event. [This tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is a bit old, but is still a good one, and will show you how to implement events in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need some kind of a shared model. The model can be processed in two ways:

1. To generate some drawings using XNA
2. To populate a tree view so you can edit it

I understand that there's a single model that defines your 2D world. So it is ok to have a static method to obtain the model that is currently loaded in your application (e.g. WorldEnvironment.Current).
Your game engine must draw what it finds in WorldEnvironment.Current. On the other hand, use Winforms to edit this WorldEnvironment.Current instance. Any changes will be visible to the other 'view' (either XNA view or WinForms). I did something similar some time ago using XNA on one window and WPF in another.

In other types of applications, I would recommend avoiding static methods, and use some Inversion of Control/Dependency Injection pattern with registered singletons or named instances if needed. But for a simple game editor I think this is the easiest way.